# Use CosmicMind material stable version with Swift 3 using carthage

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cosmicmind

I'am making an app with material design and this package looked really nice for that purpose. I have simply set up my Cartfile like this:

```
github "CosmicMind/Material" ~> 1.42.9
```

and then run:

```
carthage update
```

which gives me the following error:

```
*** Building scheme "Material iOS" in Material.xcworkspace
** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/alex/TelenorApp/MyTelenor/Carthage/Checkouts/Material/Examples/Material.xcworkspace -scheme Material iOS -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean build) failed with exit code 65:
** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

I have set up the command line tools to use XCode 8, it is possible to     build using Xcode 7.3 tools (xcode-select) but it wont link with my app     that is using Swift 3 if I do that.

What is the reccomended way to use Material with Swift 3? Is it possible to make Material work with Swift 3 some other way? I would prefer to use a stable version of Material if that is possible.

Thankful for answers!

Answer (score 0):

The `master` branch supports Swift 3. So all should work in that regard :)